# Is it possible to check width of a console in which the program output is redirected to a file?

Tags: c++, windows, console, width

`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()` returns error when initialized with standard output when program output is redirected to another command or a file.

Is there any way to get a handle to console in which the program runs and get its width no matter if program output is written on console or not ?

Maybe `GetConsoleWindow()` is here a help, but I don't know how to use handle that it produces to get the width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question makes little sense. If output is redirected then your console window width doesn't matter at all. Only the console, if any, of the program that displays the redirected output matters. You can't guess the window size of, say, Notepad.

You can however get a handle for the console, you need to use CreateFile():

```
HANDLE hConsole = CreateFile(L"CONOUT$", 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info = {0};
BOOL ok = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &info);
printf("OK = %d, %d x %d\n", ok, 
    info.srWindow.Right - info.srWindow.Left + 1, 
    info.srWindow.Bottom - info.srWindow.Top + 1);
```

Output in redirected file:

> OK = 1, 80 x 25

Comment: `error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '1' to 'void* CreateFileA(LPCSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, DWORD, DWORD, HANDLE)'` - so, now what to do ?

Comment: Tsk, tsk, still not using Unicode.  Remove the L in front of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), in particular the `srWindow` member of [`CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but what handle to use in case of using pipes ?

Comment: @rsk82, I know there's a function to get the handle of the console attached to the current process, if any. Sorry I don't know it off the top of my head.